# Flutter GoRouter Shell Route with Parent Navigator Key

Tags: flutter, nested, parent, flutter-go-router

Using `GoRouter`, a `GoRoute` can be added a parent `ShellRoute's` navigator by using the `parentNavigatorKey` property.

However, there are certain situations where it would be necessary for that `GoRoute`'s direct parent `ShellRoute` to also be added along with the GoRoute `itself`.

Imagine a parent navigator is adding sheets that govern their own transitions and contain their own `ShellRoutes` that provide a navigator for pages.

I would like to add the new sheet to the parent sheet navigator. That sheet contains its own navigator with it's own stack of pages.

This could be easily achieved if `ShellRoute` also had a `parentNavigatorKey` property so that when we push a `GoRoute` from anywhere, to a specific navigator it takes it's parent ShellRoute along with it.

```
ShellRoute(
  navigatorKey: _sheetNavigator,
  pageBuilder: (context, state, child) => CustomSheetRoute<T>(child: child),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const Page1(),
     ),
     GoRoute(
       path: '/page2',
       builder: (context, state) => const Page2(),
       routes: [
         ShellRoute(
           parentNavigatorKey: _sheetNavigator, // add this
           pageBuilder: (context, state, child) => CustomSheetRoute<T>(child: child),
           routes [
             GoRoute(
               path: '/page3',
               builder: (context, state) => const Page3(),
             ),
             GoRoute(
               path: '/page4',
               builder: (context, state) => const Page4(),
               routes: [
                 GoRoute(
                   path: '/page5',
                   builder: (context, state) => const Page5(),
                 ),
               ],
             ],
           ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

So when a go request was made to /page3 it added a `CustomSheetRoute` to the sheet navigator and showed page 3 inside that new navigator.

IS this possible?

Comment: This is possible by modifying the source code of GoRouter. It seems the code does support it but isn't currently included in the lates release. The modification requires only the removal of one line in route.dart, the addition of one line in route.dart and change to one line in builder.dart. I will post a PR about it on the official repository shortly.